# OpenUI5 Drag & Drop from and into a Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, sapui5

**EDIT:**
This Question is outdated.

If someone googled for a similar feature, take a look at [this example with sap.m.Table](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableDnD/preview). DnD is now supported in `ListBase` as of [v1.54](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/85a913571162684284853b79192e7aeba0c3d80a). Since [sap.m.Tree](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Tree/overview) extends from `ListBase` (as `sap.m.Table` does), I guess performing DnD between multiple Trees should be possible there as well.

(As **boghyon** has commented)

---

i am trying to Drag & Drop Items from an [OpenUI5-Tree](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/Tree.html) into another Tree.
Use-Case:
The User should be able to choose a TreeItem and Drop it into the Middle of the Screen (into another Tree). In that Tree the User should be able to sort the choosen Items per Drag & Drop.

My Problem is that i can only Drag things, but i can't drop them into the Tree. I made the Tree droppable, but it doesn't work.

Here you have a little Example:
[JsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/lonevavazi/3/edit?html,output)
I am trying to drag and drop items into the right Table.

**I am using Google Chrome version 41. Unfortunately i can't drag items with Firefox. I don't know why...**

Comment: If someone googled for a similar feature, take a look at this [example with `sap.m.Table`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableDnD/preview). DnD is now supported in `ListBase` as of [v1.54](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/85a913571162684284853b79192e7aeba0c3d80a). Since [`sap.m.Tree`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Tree/overview) extends from `ListBase` (as `sap.m.Table` does), I guess performing DnD between multiple Trees should be possible there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 3 hours, i got the solution.
Here you have a sample:
[JS-Bin Solution](http://jsbin.com/kavamaxufi/1/edit?html,output)

I had to use jquery events like that:

```
$("#" + sap.ui.getCore().byId("middleTree").getId()).on("drop", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();  
            event.stopPropagation();
            alert("Dropped!");
    });

$("#" + sap.ui.getCore().byId("middleTree").getId()).on("dragover", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();  
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).addClass('dragging');
    });

$("#" + sap.ui.getCore().byId("middleTree").getId()).on("dragleave", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();  
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).removeClass('dragging');
    });
```

**EDIT:**
While it is better to use SAP/OPEN UI5s method [attachBrowserEvent](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#attachBrowserEvent) i can't actually use it with a Tree, because it doesn't extend Control [sap.ui.core.Control.](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html)

Comment: Your JS Bin example doesn't work for me. Tried with Firefox 42 and latest Windows build of chromium. Any idea? Does it still work for you?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately doesn't work in firefox, but in chrome.